# How to use metric='correlation' with KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I am trying to use

KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=15, algorithm='ball_tree', metric='correlation')

However, I get the error

ValueError: Metric 'correlation' not valid for algorithm 'ball_tree'

Why is it not possible to use ball_tree? Am I limited to using brute? I have a huge matrix and would like to avoid brute. But, I can't pass in a custom metric that computes the pearson correlation between two vectors because the triangle inequality is not preserved. Any alternatives to this?

I am on scikit-learn==0.18.1

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following documentation:

[Ball Tree Documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree)

The default distance metric is minkowski for ball_tree.  Correlation isn't a valid distance metric to use for that algorithm.